# How to set a Popup to be always visible on the top in GWT

Tags: gwt, popup, position

I have a loading popup that I need to display on the top of the page, even if the user scroll down.

What I tried so far is to set the popup position as follows

```
setPopupPosition(Window.getClientWidth()/2 , 0);
```

The popup shows up on the absolut top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is this

```
 setPopupPosition(Window.getClientWidth()/2 , Window.getScrollTop());
```

Answer (score 7):

The situation can be resolved easily if you view it from a different angle: Not the popup position should adjust to the page - instead, the page should scroll behind the centering popup, e.g.:

```java
final ScrollPanel scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(scrollPanel);
pagePanel = new FlowPanel();
scrollPanel.setWidget(pagePanel);
pagePanel.add(...);
```

Now add the entire page contents to `pagePanel` (instead of adding them directly to rootPanel).

Then you can create popups like this:

```java
final PopupPanel popupPanel = new PopupPanel();
popupPanel.add(...);
popupPanel.center();
```

You'll still have to re-center the popup when the window resizes, but apart from that, the popup will always be at the center in front of the scrolling page.

Comment: It's difficult to change the layout of the application in my case

Comment: I think you should work to change a misconceived layout. Two reasons why: 1. if the layout cannot be easily changed - it is misconceived. 2. not good working kluges around a misconceived layout. OTOH, you would first need to understand what a good layout architecture would be. If you are not using any MVP and your UI is complex, it is not a good layout and consequently not a good app.

Comment: I'am actually using MVP and UIBinder, so changing the layout it's not the issue. The thing is I don't want to change something that works. I found already a simpler solution without touching the layout.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can implement `Window.addWindowScrollHandler`. It will always be on top whatever you do.

```java
DialogBox dialog = new DialogBox();
dialog.setWidget(...);
Window.addWindowScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onWindowScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
        dialog.setPopupPosition((Window.getClientWidth() - widthOfDialog) / 2, event.getScrollTop());
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.. Thanks..

Comment: here `widthOfDialog` is your actual width of dialog something like 300.