# How to center a popup/dialog window in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a list of records, each record has a button that opens setting window. Also I have preferences with a lot of logical parts and each part has some records with a button.

So, when I click on a button, dialog window appears, but if this button is somewhere in the bottom the page (let it be 300 records with button), my dialog window appears on the top. As a result I have to scroll up in order to find this window (sometimes it appears behind browser borders).

Or just imagine that you configure something and scroll page down filling each option, at the end you saves your configuration but some fields were filled incorrectly and warning popup window appears... somewhere on page, but not near your pointer or even not in the middle of your current page.

All my dialog windows are inherited from DialogBox, so I use super.show() and super.center(), but it doesn't work as I want it to.

Small info addition: some dialog windows receive data from server and when all the data is received the rest of the window is displayed. I suspect this can cause sometimes window to appear in a wrong place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a Popup to be always visible on the top in GWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045546/how-to-set-a-popup-to-be-always-visible-on-the-top-in-gwt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right that editing the content of the dialog box after it is centered will cause it to appear uncentered.  To solve this issue I called center after the content is loaded.  You can display a loading spinner or something in the meantime.

In some cases, the size of the widget you added cannot be calculated immediately.  Unfortunately the best way I found to deal with this was to add the widget and then run

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
    public void execute() {
        dialogBox.center();
    }
});
```

(unchecked code)

This ended up being so common that I added a method called `scheduleCenter` to my DialogBox class.

You can also call center more than once - each time will re-run the centering calculations.  This causes a little bit of jerking.  If you don't want any jerking around, then you'll have to set the size of the interior widget explicitly:

```
DialogBox dialogBox = new DialogBox();
dialogBox.add(myWidgetWhichWillLoadDataLater);
myWidgetWhichWillLoadDataLater.addStyleName(styleNameWhichSetsSizeExplicitly)
dialogBox.center();
```

You could also call myWidgetWhichWillLoadDataLater.setHeight("300px"), etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
DialogBox box = new DialogBox();
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(box);
RootLayoutPanel.get().setWidgetBottomHeight(box, 0, null, 0, null);
box.center();
box.show();
```

setWidgetBottomHeight() method to position exactly.

Comment: Do never ever add `DialogBox` to a panel unless you _really_ know what you're doing. In 99.999% of the cases, it's a mistake. Also, you don't need to call `show()` if you call `center()`.

Comment: Hm, when I call center before show, no dialog box appears at all. I think I have to play with show and center, hm.

Comment: @Dipak : I'll try. But I have a question, beforehand, should this work correctly for the case when data is received from server and the rest of dialog window is constructed according to this data?

Comment: @Dragon : You mean this kind of scenario:: input something to textBox-> process that value in server side -> display a message according to the result from server ::: i think it can be worked out. 
Add component to dialogue box according to the response from server.

Comment: @Dipak Strange, but my buttons don't react on such kind of dialog box center and show. I'd share some code, but I don't know what part of code should I show because it is too complex (deep inheritance) to take short example and show that "dialog box is displayed here".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22454/discussion-between-dipak-and-dragon)

Comment: @Dragon : With out looking at your code, cant say anything, did you done it in button event listener? adding some sample code to the question will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
DialogBox box = new DialogBox();
//Populate the box
box.center()
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: @gung there you go :)

Comment: your comment doesn't explain box.center(), and the code doesn't compile.